# How to efficiently calculate duration between two timestamps including date in java?

Tags: java

I have two time stamps which is in UTC with format `2021-05-19T03:03:55.095Z`  and `2021-05-19T05:10:48.177Z` . How can i calculate duration between these two in minutes even when there is date change happened. For example date of second time stamp changed to 2021-05-20T05:10:48.177Z.
Below are the few parser which i have done can anyone help me with this.

```
private String timeParser (String timestamp){
    String output = "";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    try {
        Date date1 = df.parse(timestamp);
        DateFormat outputFormatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        output = outputFormatter1.format(date1); //
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
    return output;
}


 public void calculateDuration(JsonNode aggEvent, JsonNode newEvent){
    Timestamp createdTimestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(timeParser("2021-05-19T03:03:55.095Z"));
    Timestamp newTimestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(timeParser("2021-05-20T05:10:48.177Z"));
    float timeDifference = newTimestamp.getTime() - createdTimestamp.getTime();
    float minutesDifference = (timeDifference / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
    System.out.println(Math.round(minutesDifference * 100.0) / 100.0);
}
```

Can someone correct here if im doing anything wrong?

Comment: I would recommend the usage of the `java.time` classes, replacing `Date` with `ZonedDateTime` and also has a `Duration` class to compute the difference between two date time objects using a simple `between` method. (If you are using java 8 or above)

Comment: With java-time, it gets as simple as `ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(Instant.parse("2021-05-19T03:03:55.095Z"), Instant.parse("2021-05-19T05:10:48.177Z"))`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I would also recommend you don't use `float`. It doesn't have nearly enough precision for this kind of use, or indeed most uses.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Does your code work as expected? What more precisely was your question? If you have any error message or incorrect result, please paste it into your question along with the result that you had expected. We’d like to help if you tell us what the problem is with which we should help you.

Comment: No there is no error with my code. Just wanted to clarify what could be the efficient and simple to calculate difference b/w two time stamps. The code i written is long and it not accurate when i observed the output.

Comment: Great, thanks for replying. I that case your question belongs on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry didn't know about that. Thanks for the quick help i think i will go with  ernest_k answer.

Comment: On my computer your code printed `6.88`. Is that the expected output? Do you want the minutes, with fraction, between the two times, ignoring hours and days that have also passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your issues

There are the following issues with your code:

- You are parsing each string into a `Date`, formatting it back to a different string and finally parsing it again, this time into a `Timestamp`. It’s a detour that gives you extra complication and no gain.
- You are using the old `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Timestamp` classes. They are very poorly designed and have long been replaced by java.time, the modern and far superior date and time API. You should prefer to use the latter.
- You must never ever hardcode `Z` as a literal in your format pattern string. `Z` is an offset of zero from UTC and must be parsed as an offset, or you will get incorrect results since otherwise `SimpleDateFormat` will assume the default time zone of your JVM. You may think that in this case, where we are calculating the difference between the two times, the errors of wrong time zone will even out. Not so. For example summer time (DST) transitions in your time zone will influence the calculation that you thought you were doing in UTC, leaving you and those maintaining your code baffled.
- Lower case `hh` in the format pattern string is for hour within morning (AM) or afternoon (PM). You need upper case `HH` for hour of day.
- You should not do the time math yourself in your code. Leave it to the `Duration` class of java.time for code that is clearer to read and less error-prone.

### How to do instead

Edit: My shot at a simple and good way to obtain the time difference with days, hours, minutes and seconds:

```
    Instant createdInstant = Instant.parse("2021-05-19T03:03:55.095Z");
    Instant newInstant = Instant.parse("2021-05-20T05:10:48.177Z");
    Duration timeDifference = Duration.between(createdInstant, newInstant);
    System.out.println(timeDifference);
```

The output this far looks a bit funny if you’re not used to the ISO 8601 format for durations:

> ```
> PT26H6M53.082S
> ```

It’s straightforward to read when you know how, though. Think of the output as a period of time of 26 hours 6 minutes 53.082 seconds. Only the 24 hours were not converted to a full day, which we had wanted, and which a `Duration` can do too:

```
    System.out.println("Days: " + timeDifference.toDays());
    System.out.println("Hours: " + timeDifference.toHoursPart());
```

> ```
> Days: 1
> Hours: 2
> ```

There are similar `toMinutesPart`, `toSecondsPart` and `toMillisPart` methods.

Link: [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: The only objective is to calculate duration between two timestamps which also include dates in minutes .

Answer (score 0):

Single line of code need to be updated.

`float minutesDifference = (timeDifference / (1000 * 60));`

---

Here doing `%60` means you are covering all difference in hour, minute format

like `(timeDifference / (1000 * 60)) / 60` = noOfHours

and `(timeDifference / (1000 * 60)) % 60` = reminder of above (Minutes)

[See output of this code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java/) you will understand better.

Comment: I recommend you don’t do the time math yourself. The `Duration` class of Java can do it (since Java 9).

Comment: The page you link to is funny. It shows the worst solutions first and the best ones last. Unfortunately the last solution, using `Period`, does not fit the OP’s situation. Instead I recommend `Duration` as I have already said.